# HI! how can i use inspect element to see whats under these stars ( * )?

Tags: html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0wF4.png)

how can i remove the stars??

Answer (score 1):

That email address looks to be hashed for privacy.
Unless you have access to the source code of this site to remove the method for this string, you will not be able to remove the stars and access this email address in it's entirety.
It's probably hashed for a reason.